# How do I save an association in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to accomplish creating an association from the controller and I can't quite get it. Why wouldn't this work?

```
@document.components = @components.first if @document.automatic_component_selection?
```

Comment: Could you please give more context? What are your models? What is your controller? Thank you.

Comment: A Document can have many Components. That's it really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based in your comment then you have two options:

- `@document.components << @components.first if @document.automatic_component_selection?`
- `@document.components.create!(@components.first) if @document.automatic_component_selection?`

What you are doing with `@document.components = @components.first`  makes the collection contain only the supplied objects, by adding and deleting as appropriate.

Reference: [Rails Guides Active Record Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)s

Comment: Actually getting an `AssociationTypeMismatch` now: `AssociationTypeMismatch (Component(#46101640) expected, got NilClass(#5140600))`. Is NilClass a no record error?

Comment: That means `@components.first` is nil

Comment: Prepare a gist with your code and post it here. Really, I need more context to help you.

Comment: Line 7 works fine in the `new` method, doesn't return anything in the `create` method. https://gist.github.com/lolomet/8ede6829e8d1ecb08278

Comment: `@document = Document.new(params[:document])` does not save the record that is the reason you are getting `nil`. Use `@document = Document.create!(params[:document])`. But you should really review your controller, you are abusing of several antipatterns. Your domain logic should be in the models or in PORO objects.

Comment: I know, I know, it's bad. That `create!` though gives me the same error.

Comment: Let's switch to a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58839/discussion-between-emm-and-mvidaurre).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to add `@components.first` to that `Document` object's associated components. In that case, you can write

```
@document.components << @components.first if @document.automatic_component_selection?
```

Comment: Thank-you! Was tearing my hair out.